# Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN, how many times can I use it?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

I'm trying to build a plugin app, an app which loads some plugins... I've played a little with dynamic loading and everything was fine. Now I'm playing with static loading... and I'm stuck in the following situation:

I have two plugins, the app works with both, but not with both at the same time. In `main.cpp` I have:

```
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(RawPlugin)
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(BPlugin)
```

and in the .pro:

```
LIBS           = -L../../plugins-static -lraw
LIBS           = -L../../plugins-static -lb
```

With the above configuration, I get:

```
In function `ZN29StaticRawPluginPluginInstanceC1Ev':
C:\Users\User\Downloads\thething\source\app\build-static/../main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `qt_static_plugin_RawPlugin()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.Debug:78: recipe for target 'debug\app.exe' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug\app.exe] Error 1
```

Commenting any of the `Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN`, and the corresponding `LIBS`, lines make it work.

What I'm doing wrong?

Both plugins implement the same interface, does it matter?

```
class RawPlugin : public QObject,
                  public PluginInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "org.qt-project.Qt.Examples.PluginInterface")
    Q_INTERFACES(PluginInterface)
```

...

```
class BPlugin : public QObject,
                public PluginInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "org.qt-project.Qt.Examples.PluginInterface")
    Q_INTERFACES(PluginInterface)
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your .pro file. I'm not sure, but maybe you should change the two `LIB` lines by only one: `LIBS += -L../../plugins-static -lraw -lb` By the way, is it not enough with `LIBS += -Lplugins`

Comment: @[Tarod](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4719550/tarod)You can have two lines, he just missed the **`+`** infront of the `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is indeed with the .pro file. You have written

```
LIBS           = -L../../plugins-static -lraw
LIBS           = -L../../plugins-static -lb
```

What this does is first line sets the `LIBS` to `-L../../plugins-static -lraw` The Second line simply changes it to `-L../../plugins-static -lb`. So you end up having just one of the two libs. You should add a **`+`** infront of the `=`:

```
LIBS           += -L../../plugins-static -lraw
LIBS           += -L../../plugins-static -lb
```